# Polars solution to normalise groups by per-group reference value

Tags: python-polars

I'm trying to use Polars to normalise the values of groups of entries by a single reference value per group.

In the example data below, I'm trying to generate the column `normalised` which contains `value`s divided by the per-group `ref` reference state value,  i.e.:

```
group_id  reference_state  value  normalised
1         ref              5      1.0
1         a                3      0.6
1         b                1      0.2
2         ref              4      1.0
2         a                8      2.0
2         b                2      0.5
```

This is straightforward in Pandas:

```
for (i, x) in df.groupby("group_id"):
    ref_val = x.loc[x["reference_state"] == "ref"]["value"]
    df.loc[df["group_id"] == i, "normalised"] = x["value"] / ref_val.to_list()[0]
```

Is there a way to do this in Polars?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you next time provide the code that creates the table? That makes it easier to answer the question.

Comment: Will do, thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `window` function to make an expression operate on different groups via:

`.over("group_id")`

and then you can write the logic which divides by the values if equal to `"ref"` with:

`pl.col("value") / pl.col("value").filter(pl.col("reference_state") == "ref").first()`

Putting it all together:

```py
df = pl.DataFrame({
    "group_id": [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2],
    "reference_state": ["ref", "a", "b", "ref", "a", "b"],
    "value": [5, 3, 1, 4, 8, 2],
})

(df.with_columns([
    (
        pl.col("value") / 
        pl.col("value").filter(pl.col("reference_state") == "ref").first()
    ).over("group_id").alias("normalised")
    
]))
```

```
shape: (6, 4)
┌──────────┬─────────────────┬───────┬────────────┐
│ group_id ┆ reference_state ┆ value ┆ normalised │
│ ---      ┆ ---             ┆ ---   ┆ ---        │
│ i64      ┆ str             ┆ i64   ┆ f64        │
╞══════════╪═════════════════╪═══════╪════════════╡
│ 1        ┆ ref             ┆ 5     ┆ 1.0        │
│ 1        ┆ a               ┆ 3     ┆ 0.6        │
│ 1        ┆ b               ┆ 1     ┆ 0.2        │
│ 2        ┆ ref             ┆ 4     ┆ 1.0        │
│ 2        ┆ a               ┆ 8     ┆ 2.0        │
│ 2        ┆ b               ┆ 2     ┆ 0.5        │
└──────────┴─────────────────┴───────┴────────────┘
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do it:

1. create a temporary dataframe which, for each `group_id`, tells you the `value` where `reference_state` is `'ref'`
2. join with that temporary dataframe

```py
(
    df.join(
        df.filter(pl.col("reference_state") == "ref").select(["group_id", "value"]),
        on="group_id",
    )
    .with_column((pl.col("value") / pl.col("value_right")).alias("normalised"))
    .drop("value_right")
)
```

This gives you:

```py
Out[16]: 
shape: (6, 4)
┌──────────┬─────────────────┬───────┬────────────┐
│ group_id ┆ reference_state ┆ value ┆ normalised │
│ ---      ┆ ---             ┆ ---   ┆ ---        │
│ i64      ┆ str             ┆ i64   ┆ f64        │
╞══════════╪═════════════════╪═══════╪════════════╡
│ 1        ┆ ref             ┆ 5     ┆ 1.0        │
│ 1        ┆ a               ┆ 3     ┆ 0.6        │
│ 1        ┆ b               ┆ 1     ┆ 0.2        │
│ 2        ┆ ref             ┆ 4     ┆ 1.0        │
│ 2        ┆ a               ┆ 8     ┆ 2.0        │
│ 2        ┆ b               ┆ 2     ┆ 0.5        │
└──────────┴─────────────────┴───────┴────────────┘
```

Comment: Thanks very much, although I think the brevity of the earlier answer fits better with the approach of Polars

Comment: yup, you're right, I didn't know you could filter with `over`, there's really so much you can do with polars!